# python, argparse: enable input parameter when another one has been specified

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, argparse

In my python script, I want to be able to use an optional input parameter *only* when another optional parameter has been specified. Example:

```
$ python myScript.py --parameter1 value1
$ python myScript.py --parameter1 value1 --parameter2 value2
```

But NOT:

```
$ python myScript.py --parameter2 value2
```

How do I do this with argparse?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen if `myScript.py --parameter2 value2 --parameter1 value1`?  This is a very difficult case to deal with if you want it to pass.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 is a bug request for a `mutually_inclusive_group` feature.  That wouldn't quite work in this case, since `--parameter1` can occur without `--parameter2`.  Contribute to that issue if you have ideas of how this or related constraints could be implemented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a custom action:

```
import argparse

foo_default=None    

class BarAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
        didfoo=getattr(namespace,'foo',foo_default)
        if(didfoo == foo_default):
            parser.error( "foo before bar!")
        else:
            setattr(namespace,self.dest,values)

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo',default=foo_default)
parser.add_argument('--bar',action=BarAction,help="Only use this if --foo is set")

#testing.
print parser.parse_args('--foo baz'.split())
print parser.parse_args('--foo baz --bar cat'.split())
print parser.parse_args('--bar dog'.split())
```

This can even be done in a little easier to maintain way if you're OK with relying on some undocumented behavior of argparse:

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
first_action=parser.add_argument('--foo',dest='cat',default=None)

class BarAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
        didfoo=getattr(namespace,first_action.dest,first_action.default)
        if(didfoo == first_action.default):
            parser.error( "foo before bar!")
        else:
            setattr(namespace,self.dest,values)

parser.add_argument('--bar',action=BarAction,
                    help="Only use this if --foo is set")

#testing.
print parser.parse_args('--foo baz'.split())
print parser.parse_args('--foo baz --bar cat'.split())
print parser.parse_args('--bar dog'.split())
```

In this example, we get the default for `foo` and it's destination from the action object returned by `add_argument` (add_argument's return value isn't documented anywhere that I can find).  This is still a little fragile (If you want to specify a `type=` keyword to the `--foo` argument for example).

Finally, you can check `sys.argv` before parsing.

```
import sys
if ("--parameter2" in sys.argv) and ("--parameter1" not in sys.argv):
    parser.error("parameter1 must be given if parameter2 is given")
```

This gets a little more tricky if `--parameter1` could also be triggered by `--p1`, but you get the idea.  Then you could use

```
if (set(sys.argv).intersection(('--p2',...)) and 
    not set(sys.argv).intersection(('--p1',...)))
```

The advantage here is that it doesn't require any particular order.  (`--p2` doesn't need to follow `--p1` on the commandline).  And, as before, you can get the list of command strings that will trigger your particular action via the `option_strings` attribute returned by `parser.add_argument(...)`.  e.g.

```
import argparse
import sys   
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
action1=parser.add_argument('--foo')
action2=parser.add_argument('--bar',
                            help="Only use this if --foo is set")

argv=set(sys.argv)
if (( argv & set(action2.option_strings) ) and 
      not ( argv & set(action1.option_strings) )):
                #^ set intersection
     parser.error(' or '.join(action1.option_strings)+
                  ' must be given with '+
                  ' or '.join(action2.option_strings))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [parse_known_args()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) to check if `--parameter1` was given before adding `--parameter2` to the parser.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--parameter1', dest='p1')
args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
if args.p1:
  parser.add_argument('--parameter2', dest='p2')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.p1:
  print args.p1
if args.p2:
  print args.p2
```

Results:

```
$ python myScript.py --parameter1 a
a
$ python myScript.py --parameter1 a --parameter2 b
a
b
$ python myScript.py --parameter2 b
usage: myScript.py [-h] [--parameter1 P1]
myScript.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --parameter2 b
```

Comment: `--help` is going to be inaccurate though.

Answer (score 3):

One idea would be to manually check the output of calling `parser.parse_args()` and raise an exception or otherwise fail if `--parameter2` is used but `--parameter1` isn't.

You could also try setting a [custom action](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action) (scroll down a bit) to `--parameter2` check if `--parameter1` exists inside the namespace.

Finally, you could try using [subparsers](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#other-utilities), although I don't know if it'll let you specify a value for `--parameter1`.