# argparse arguments nesting

Tags: python, argparse

I have a following code in python:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Deployment tool')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-a', '--add', dest='name_to_add', help='Add a new group or a role to existing group')
group.add_argument('-u', '--upgrade', dest='name_to_upgrade', help='Upgrade a group with the new version')
parser.add_argument('--web_port', help='Port of the WEB instance that is being added to the group')
```

My problem is with "--web_port" option. I want to be able to add this option only with "-a" option but not with "-u".

I **want** to be able to run: "python my_script.py -a name --web_port=XXXX".

I **don't want** to be able to run: "python my_script.py -u name --web_port=XXXX"

How should I change my code in order to be able to run it this way?

Thanks, Arshavski Alexander.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python, argparse: enable input parameter when another one has been specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455218/python-argparse-enable-input-parameter-when-another-one-has-been-specified)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Instead of having `-a` and `-u` be options, you may want to make them subcommands. Then, make `--web-port` an option of the `add` subcommand:

```
python my_script.py add name --web_port=XXXX
python my_script.py upgrade name
```

Something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Deployment tool')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

add_p = subparsers.add_parser('add')
add_p.add_argument("name")
add_p.add_argument("--web_port")
...

upg_p = subparsers.add_parser('upgrade')
upg_p.add_argument("name")
...
```

If you try run

```
my_script.py upgrade name --web_port=1234
```

you'll get an error for unrecognized argument "--web_port".

Likewise, if you try

```
my_script.py add name upgrade
```

you'll get an error for unrecognized argument "upgrade", since
you only defined a single positional argument for the 'add' subcommand.

In other words, subcommands are implicitly mutually exclusive. The only
tiny wart is that you need to add the "name" positional parameter to each
subparser.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. But I need add and upgrade to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: As subcommands, they would be. `python my_script.py add name --web_port=XXX upgrade`, for example, would treat `upgrade` as a positional argument to the `add` subcommand, not an invocation of the  `upgrade` subcommand. (I think; I haven't implemented subcommands in a while.)