# argparse: setting optional argument with value of mandatory argument

Tags: python, default-value, argparse

With Python's [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html), I would like to add an optional argument that, if not given, gets the value of another (mandatory) argument.

```py
parser.add_argument('filename',
                    metavar = 'FILE',
                    type    = str,
                    help    = 'input file'
                    )

parser.add_argument('--extra-file', '-f',
                    metavar = 'ANOTHER_FILE',
                    type    = str,
                    default = ,
                    help    = 'complementary file (default: FILE)'
                    )
```

I could of course manually check for `None` after the arguments are parsed, but isn't there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this that is more clean than:

```
ns = parser.parse_args()
ns.extra_file = ns.extra_file if ns.extra_file else ns.filename
```

(just like you propose in your question).

You *could* probably do some [custom action gymnastics similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11455440/748858), but I really don't think that would be worthwhile (or "pythonic").

Comment: `ns.extra_file = ns.extra_file or ns.filename`

Comment: @kindall this works for filenames, but imagine doing this for an optional boolean argument that has been set to `False` by the user. You might check for `None`.

Answer (score 2):

This has slightly different semantics than your original set of options, but may work for you:

```
parse.add_argument('filename', action='append', dest='filenames')
parse.add_argument('--extra-file', '-f', action='append', dest='filenames')
args = parse.parse_args()
```

This would replace `args.filename` with a list `args.filenames` of at least one file, with `-f` appending its argument to that list. Since it's possible to specify `-f` on the command line before the positional argument, you couldn't on any particular order of the input files in `args.filenames`.

---

Another option would be to dispense with the `-f` option and make `filename` a multi-valued positional argument:

```
parse.add_argument('filenames', nargs='+')
```

Again, `args.filenames` would be a list of at least one filename. This would also interfere if you have other positional arguments for your script.

Comment: It's a versatile idea to have the `filename` actually be a list and then check for `len(..)==2`. Given the relative simplicity of the problem, however, I guess I'll stick to checking whether `extra_file` is `None` -- it wouldn't change the complexity of the program anyways.